# How to format a scene in SKSpriteKit for Simulator AND Physical Device

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, xcode7, skspritenode, skview

I am having a problem formatting the scene for a simple game using SKSpriteKit.
In the simulator, my scene looks exactly how I want, but on a physical device it does not.

[This is what is looks like in the Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1dH2.png)

[This is what it looks like on my Ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egY3P.jpg)

Once I run this on a physical device(my iPad), all i get is a zoomed in picture of the background.

Here is my GameViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var scene: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Configure the view
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    //Create and configure the scene
    //create scene within size of skview
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    //present the scene
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}


override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .Landscape
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Additionally Here is my GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//background
var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Basketball")
//isStarted & GameOver
var isStarted = false
var isGameOver = false
//
var Ball: Basketball_Ball!
var Rim1: Rim!
var Rim2: Rim!
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
func addBackground(){
    //background
    background.zPosition = 0
    background.size = self.frame.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    addChild(background)

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
func addBall() {
    Ball = Basketball_Ball()
    addChild(Ball)
    Ball.loadAppearance()
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
func addRims() {
    Rim1 = Rim()
    addChild(Rim1)
    Rim1.loadAppearance()

    Rim2 = Rim()
    addChild(Rim2)
    Rim2.loadAppearance_Rim2()
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    addBackground()
    addBall()
    addRims()
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    }

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Does the problem lie in my use of scene.scaleMode in my GameViewController file?

Do I need to upload different sizes for each image in my Assets Folder?

Comment: On your iPad, the app is running in iPhone compatibility mode, indicating your app supports iPhone only. Do you want to target iPhone *and* iPad? Change the target settings in your Xcode project to make your app a universal app and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track!